# How can I pass a keyword argument to a function when the name contains a dot `.`?

Tags: python, syntax, keyword-argument

Given a function that accepts "**kwargs", e.g.,

```py
def f(**kwargs):
     print(kwargs)
```

how can I pass a key-value pair if the key contains a dot/period (`.`)?

The straightforward way results in a syntax error:

```py
In [46]: f(a.b=1)
  Cell In[46], line 1
    f(a.b=1)
      ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Comment: What would you expect this to do? How should the function "know" which kind of object to create?

Comment: @mozway, print `{'a.b': 1}`

Comment: Then `f(**{'a.b': 1})`

Comment: **kwargs is a dictionary, so accessing this would be done via kwargs.get('a.b',0) or kwargs['a.b']

Comment: This really seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python functions only accepts [valid python names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) (letters, underscore, and digits except for the first character), a dot is not allowed.

If you want to have a **string** `a.b` as parameter, then you must use a dictionary

```
f(**{'a.b': 1})
# {'a.b': 1}
```

You can combine this with other parameters:

```
f(x=2, **{'a.b': 1})
# {'x': 2, 'a.b': 1}
```